# Sending HTML template through mail using node js node mailer

Tags: html, node.js

I had written node mailer code from w3schools. I want to send the html template designed (index.html in my case). Below is the code. please help me how can i send html template to the mail using node js.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var data = require('index.html');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'youremail@gmail.com',
    pass: 'yourpassword'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'youremail@gmail.com',
  to: 'myfriend@yahoo.com',
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  html: 'data'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

Comment: Your code looks correct except this line `html: 'data'` this should be `html: data`

Comment: You should require `index.html`, you should read that file through `fs` module.

Answer (score 4):

This is the right way of passing html in the `nodemailer`

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var fs = require('fs');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'youremail@gmail.com',
    pass: 'yourpassword'
  }
});


fs.readFile('index.html', {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function (err, html) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    var mailOptions = {
      from: 'youremail@gmail.com',
      to: 'myfriend@yahoo.com',
      subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
      html: html
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Index.html file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Node js Email </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
      </head>


      <body>
        <div class="container"><br />
          <h1>Send Email</h1><br />
          <form onsubmit="sentthis()" method="post">
            <div class="divi">
                <label for="to"></label>To:</label>
                <input type="email" class="too" name="to">
              </div>


            <div class="divi">

                <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
                <input type="text" class="subjectt" name="subject">
              </div>
            <div class="divi">
                  <p>Body:</p>
                  <textarea cols="" rows="5"class="textarea" name="body"></textarea>
                </div>
            <div class="divi">
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Send</button>
              </div>
          </form>
      </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

server.js file

```
    var express = require('express'),
        path = require('path'),
        nodeMailer = require('nodemailer'),
        bodyParser = require('body-parser');

        var app = express();
        app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
        app.use(express.static('public'));
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
        app.use(bodyParser.json());
        var port = 3000;
        app.get('/', function (req, res) {
          res.render('index.html');
        });
        app.post('/sent',function(req,res){
          let transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
              host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
              port: 465,
              secure: true,
              auth: {
                  user: 'marcus251@gmail.com',
                  pass: 'yourpassword'
              }
          });
          let mailOptions = {
              from: '"Marcus coffee" <marcus251@gmail.com>', 
              to: "Receiver Name <receiver@email.com>",
              subject: req.body.subject, 
              text: req.body.body, 


          };

          transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
              if (error) {
                  return console.log(error);
              }
              console.log('Message  sent: ', info.messageId, info.response);
                  res.render('index.html');
              });
          });
              app.listen(port, function(){
                console.log('Server is running at port: ',port);
              });
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: yes I was working on a project which called api on a web page and thats why I used app.post so to manage the routing procedure.

Comment: any ways the below provided solution is an individual script for sending email

Comment: if someone needs explaination how this code works just let me know